# Coldfusion 10 on Mavericks Apple Server App Broken

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mac, coldfusion

I run the Apple Server App to host my local dev sites, and have Coldfusion 10. I upgraded to Mavericks and that broke the Server app, said I needed to upgrade to Server 3.0 which I did, but now CF isn't working - admin not available, pages just displaying their raw code. A few blog posts point to a broken connector, but it's way over my head on how it might be fixed. Any ideas?

Comment: There's an open bug fix for this, but in the meantime there's an easy fix in the comments https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3653076

Comment: Yeah, the fix in the comments doesn't work for me. I'm not using the OSX built in web server, but rather the Apple Server app - I guess the subtle difference is enough to stop the fix working. For now I'm using the built in CF server alongside the Server app, but it's not a very tidy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the answer on Stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366358/webserver-not-working-on-osx-mavericks/20367252#20367252

The short answer is:

1. Install Java 7 JDK
2. Manually change `/Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion/bin/jvm.xml` to use the new JVM

Comment: Not sure this will work - think I had to do something like this when I initially got it setup with Mountain Lion. For me CF is running fine, it's just that it's not working with my Apache install. I'll give it a go though, can't hurt.

Comment: as below, update has been live for a while now, but the above was a valid fix

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this thread. ColdFusion 10 is now supported on OS X 10.9 Maverick with the release of [CF10 Update 13](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-update-13-released).

This should work for you now.